# How does android run java applications if it doesnt have a JVM

Tags: java, android

How does android run java programs if it doesnt have a JVM, i know theres a delvik vm but what does it do ? and how does it run java applications?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)

Comment: Google and wikipedia may be of use sometimes…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Programs are commonly written in a dialect of Java and compiled to
>   bytecode. Then they are converted from Java Virtual Machine-compatible
>   .class files to Dalvik-compatible .dex (Dalvik Executable) files
>   before installation on a device.

[Dalvik (software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29)

Answer (score 5):

Android can't run java applications. It runs "Android" applications written in Java that get complied down to the dalvik bytecode.